# Training NER model with Spacy only uses one core

Tags: multiprocessing, spacy

When I train a NER model with Spacy and monitor my CPU I can see that it is only using 1 core.

I have found only one example of multiprocessing in the Spacy documentation but it is not applied to the training: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/pipeline/multi_processing.py
I am just using the training code provided in the examples but with a list of 500000 tuples in the TRAINING_DATA following the same structure: ("rawtext", {"entities": [(entity_start_offset, entity_end_offset, "ENTITY")]})

```
with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER
    for itn in range(n_iter):
        random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
        losses = {}
        batches = spacy.util.minibatch(TRAIN_DATA,
                            size=spacy.util.compounding(4., 32., 1.001))
        for i, batch in enumerate(batches):
            print(i)
            texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
            # Updating the weights
            nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer,
                       drop=0.35, losses=losses)
        print('Losses', losses)
```

I need to speed up the training using multiple cores. Right now, it takes 40 min per epoc using 1 single core.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like since version 2.1, the training in Spacy is only done with one single core. (https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3507) I find it a little bit weird when parallelization of the matrix multiplications has been proben to be worth in other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

According to docs: https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#multiprocessing (spaCy 3)

**spaCy includes built-in support for multiprocessing with nlp.pipe
using the n_process option:**

```
# Multiprocessing with 4 processes
docs = nlp.pipe(texts, n_process=4)

# With as many processes as CPUs (use with caution!)
docs = nlp.pipe(texts, n_process=-1)
```